# Is the phrase "the long way of the oval" the object of the clause and should there be an "into" before it?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning, objects

I encountered this sentence when reading "A Morbid Taste for Bones" by Ellis Peters:

> Cadfael turned towards the cry, thrusting through thorn-branches, and came out in a narrow oval of grass surrounded every way with thick bushes, through which a used track no wider than a man's shoulders clove, the long way of the oval.

I under stand that the clause "through which a used track no wider than a man's shoulders clove" refers to "thick bushes", but what is the role of "the long way of the oval"? Is it the indirect object of "a used track"? So "a used track cleaves through the bushes into the oval"? But it does not have a preposition before it.

Thank you for your help!

Edit:

This is what I imagine based on @TRomano's comments:

[image]

The black curves are the bushes, and the blue path is the track.

Comment: The track goes through the thorn bushes and extends  the length of the oval, not across its width.  *The long way of the oval* is an absolute adjunct or an absolute appositive.  You can understand it like this:  a track   ... (it being) the long way of the oval.

Comment: @TRomano: Thank you, I see. It now sounds grammatically correct, but not easy to imagine. So the track has two parts, one part is through the bush, then it continues along the length of the oval, is that right?

Comment: @TRomano: I see! Just saw your edit.

Comment: Imagine this as oval rather than round, and the perimeter of the circle (oval) a hedge of thorn bushes: Ø  The narrow track cuts through the thorn bushes and runs the length of the oval.

Comment: @TRomano: Sounds more like ʔ, but I got it. Thank you!

Comment: I imagine the track exiting the oval through the thorn hedge on the far side.

Comment: @TRomano: Is the picture what you meant?

Comment: I don't imaging the narrow track *ending* at the far edge, but continuing through it, exiting on the far side (or entering there, if you're coming from that direction). The track *cleaves through* the thorn hedge.  Also, I imagine the track extending along the long axis of the oval, not cleaving to the perimeter. It cleaves **through**, not **to** the thorn hedge.  **Cleave** meaning "to cut through", not **cleave** meaning "to cling to".

Comment: @TRomano: OK. So the "long way" means the "long axis", not the "long perimeter". Thank you!

Comment: Yes, the long axis. (typo in my last comment, "imagine" not "imaging").

Answer (score 1):

The narrow track (or path) cuts through the "egg shaped" grassy patch in a (roughly) straight line along the long axis.

"Clove" is a past tense of "cleave" meaning split (not cleaved meaning stuck together)  The track is "used" so it is quite clear of bushes, since the people that use it will keep it clear. The track probably extends beyond the bushes and further through the surrounding woods